# Compiler discrepancy in expression evaluation

Tags: c, compiler-construction, compiler-errors

I have implemented the following function to emulate if-then-else:

```
int foo(int x, int y, int z) {
  int negOne = (1<<31)>>31;
  int test = !(~x + !x) + negOne;

  int ans = (test & y) | (~test & z);

  return ans;
}
```

I have certain restrictions, and the top part was a bit of a hack, but it works.  test only evaluates to either 0 or -1.

The assignment uses a specific compiler, and in the case of x = 0, y = -2147483648, and z = 2147483647, the compiler states that my code is returning -2147483648.

That wouldn't make sense since if x = 0, then test = 0.  If test = 0, then the ans expression will evaluate to z, i.e., 2147483647.

I have double-checked my outputs on two different compilers and it says I am returning 2147483647, the correct answer, so I'm left to assume this is a compiler error, perhaps related to the bounds of an integer?  Unless of course, the fault is in my code.

Also additional compiler info:
The compiler is called the dlc compiler.  I previously had "parse error" issues declaring my variables in the middle of my functions, and I was told the compiler was likely C89.  Moving these declarations to the top of the function fixed the problem.

UPDATE:
changing the negOne expression to ~1 + 1 did not fix anything.
I evaluated both sides of the ans expressions and, as expected, they evaluated to 0 and 2147483647, respectively, so that does not seem to be the problem either. The express would then finally evaluate 0 | 2147483647, which is 2147483647; and that's what the value of ans is, and I also checked the value of the variable receiving the return value of the function, and again, it is 2147483647.

So I'm still perplexed as to why one particular compiler returns -2147483648.

Comment: Can you try to provide a little meta-information as to what you're trying to do? Do you want `negOne` to be 31 zeros and a one? Why not do `uint32_t negOne = 1`? What are x, y, z? Why are they not bools? What is the compiler?

Comment: @mga Well the solution of the problem is not the issue for me.  The function is supposed to emulate  x ? y : z.  Due to the restrictions of the assignment, I'm limited in what things I can use, so that's not something I can change.  I just can't figure out why one specific  compiler is spitting out the wrong number.

Answer (score 1):

You're code may be exhibiting undefined behaviour if `int` is 32-bits wide on the machine you're trying this. Left shifting from Standard C99 §6.5.7 (emphasis mine):

> The result of E1 << E2 is E1 left-shifted E2 bit positions; vacated bits are filled with zeros. If E1 has an unsigned type, the value of the result is E1×2<sup>E2</sup>, reduced modulo one more than the maximum value representable in the result type. **If E1 has a signed type and non-negative value, and E1×2<sup>E2</sup> is representable in the result type, then that is the resulting value; otherwise, the behaviour is undefined.**

The literal `1` is a signed `int` i.e. E1 here is an signed integer and has a non-negative value `1`. 1 × 2<sup>31</sup> = 2,147,483,648 which isn't representable on a machine with 32-bit integer, since `signed int` range on such a machine is -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647.

All bets are off when you're in the UB land, thus any output is possible. I don't understand why you can't do this:

```
int negOne = -1;
```

Comment: I've been working on this assignment for 10 hours a day, little sleep between each day so the negOne expression was very hacky.  We are limited in our expressions for this assignment (no - expression allowed, for instance).  I just as easily did negOne = ~1 + 1 to get it to equal -1, and the error still remains, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem what happens, when You use that specific compiler is simpe overflow. Because different compilers use different order of operations when certain order is not strictly specified, the output of this code is not deterministic. In particular case I think addition is causing an overflow.

there is described some good examples of such traps here: http://www.fefe.de/intof.html.

Sometimes these traps are unintentionally avoided with optimization made by compiler before compiling. So I would suggest to take disassembly of the output of all compilers You used - then the point of overflow comes up straight away and the differences are also made clear.

I would suggest You to use something like this for conditional emulation:

```
int foo(int x, int y, int z) {
  int test = ~(!!x) + 1;
  return (test & y) | (~test & z);
}
```

This should avoid overflows with representing x as "boolean" in older C standards as well.

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not solve the error.  After testing other functions in this assignment, though, I have another instance or two of edge cases that work just fine in other compilers (highest int possible, lowest int), but not in the one I used, so I assume that some strange overflow problem is a likely culprit.  Thank you regardless.

Comment: @SpagGuy: Could You post these other assignments? Maybe we can sort out what is wrong there?